# How to let a java application deal with a bash script in ubuntu

Tags: java, bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I want to make a reading entry for my java application to get some data from a bash script which runs regularly, so that my application can store the data in a database each time .

any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the bash script start your Java program and supply data through command line parameters.

Comment: Read up how to call a Java application from command line. Arguments passed to a Java program are placed in the String array which `main()` gets passed.

Answer (score 1):

Does the bash script print that info to stdout? Is it possible that you launch the bash script from the java application?

In that case you can do something like

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("bash-script").start();
```

And you can get stdout from the process with `p.getInputStream();`